# Using jQuery with Spring Webflow. How do I pass everything in the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, spring-webflow

I am having a issue with Spring Webflow and JQuery.

I am using JQuery to check for the user changing the value in a dropdown box but once the user selects a new value in the dropdown box I need to change the eventID so spring webflow knows what I am trying to do and to post the fall form with all of the html..

Here is the old code that used to work before the firm requested that I removed dijit and use jquery only

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Spring.addDecoration(new Spring.ElementDecoration({
        elementId : "borough",
        widgetType : "dijit.form.Select",
        widgetAttrs : {
            promptMessage : "Enter Borough",
            required : true, 
            onChange : function() {
                Spring.remoting.submitForm(
                   'submit',
                   'member', 
                   {_eventId: 'loadSchools', fragments:'contents'}
               ); 
        return false;
    } }}));
</script>
```

now here is the new code that looks like it does change the eventID and does the post but I need all the data from the form on the post

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#borough").change(function() {
            $.post('${flowExecutionUrl}', {_eventId: 'loadSchools'}, function(){
                alert('eventid was sent to url');
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Can some someone help me out here....

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the form data like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#borough").change(function() {

        // first, populate hidden field with the event ID
        $('input[name="_eventId"]').val('loadSchools');

        // serialize the form fields to a URL string
        var params = $('#myForm').serialize();

        $.post('${flowExecutionUrl}', params, function(){
            alert('eventid was sent to url');
        });
    });
});
```

where you have a hidden input in your form, eg. `<input type="hidden" name="_eventId" />`. Hope that helps.

Comment: this works better but still NO GOT... I see the server is getting the right eventID now but the browser is not taking the new JSP page!

Comment: Worked for me with Spring Boot 2 (found the Model as the form action does)